# Permission denied warning with function.file-put-contents

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm using this code to download a dynamic image file which is already on my server

```
$url = 'example.com/test/image.php';
$img = 'cert.png';
file_put_contents($img,'file_get_contents($url));
```

allow_url_fopen is already enabled on the server. but i'm still getting the following error

```
Warning: file_put_contents(cert.png) [function.file-put-contents]: failed 
to open stream: Permission denied in D:/... on line 42
```

I saw the same error on another website http://www.rsi-relief.com/rsi-links/ergonomics-information/ergoweb/

I'm new to PHP so i'm a bit confused here. Pls help

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the file? You need to give the Apache user permission

Comment: I tried it thru FTP but failed. can u pls tell me how to give those permissions or sm reference article?

Comment: dude, your previous question has been closed due to too localized. if you want to have a better chance, you should edit your question with something more meaningful (such as include your FTP code, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with wrong php code i guess, but file system permissions on your server  /host. If you have access via SSH or FTP you can try to modify the cmod settings of your folder / file.

**Update**

Your code is wrong, try this

```
// this is the path where you need write access on your server
$imgDestinationPath = '/you/need/a/physical/serverpath/here/cert.png';
$url = 'http://example.com/test/image.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($imgDestinationPath, $content);
```

Comment: I already tried it. But whenever i try to change permission, it says   Status: Set permissions of '/httpdocs/test' to '777'
Command: CWD /httpdocs
Response: 250 CWD command successful.
Command: SITE CHMOD 777 test
Response: 500 'SITE CHMOD 777 test': command not understood

Comment: Im sorry that stackoverflow truncated my http:// i just wanted to make sure that you have tried it:) Have you checked my update yet?

Comment: @ Grrbrr404 after trying ur code, i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "Permission denied in D:/" looks like you are on a windows host our maybe your local machine. Are you sure you have $imageDestinationPath = D:\anypathhere\cert.png ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6028/discussion-between-anurag-and-grrbrr404)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of command line, I suggest you try with filezilla or some FTP client, right click on the directory and click on file permissions. then tick appropriate permission and click ok. This should work